# from JavaScript to React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can someone help me to change this JS code to React class?

```
function Ball(x, y, radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.dx = randomDx();
    this.dy = randomDy();
    this.mass = this.radius * this.radius * this.radius;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = randomColor();
    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(Math.round(this.x), Math.round(this.y), this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)';
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    };
    this.speed = function() {
        // magnitude of velocity vector
        return Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
    };
    this.angle = function() {
        //angle of ball with the x axis
        return Math.atan2(this.dy, this.dx);
    };
    this.onGround = function() {
        return (this.y + this.radius >= canvas.height)
    }
}
```

This code is intended to show balls in the canvas that collide with each other and change their direction and speed (like real balls). My problem is that I cannot correctly change the JavaScript code to React.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class CanvasDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.initCanvas = this.initCanvas.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
     this.initCanvas()
  }
  initCanvas(){
     const {x,y,radius,dx,dy,.....} = this.props
     let ele = document.getElementById("canvasTest")
     ....
  }
  render() {     
   <div>
    <canvas id="canvasTest"></canvas>
  </div>}
}
```